# Refresh TextSize of Item of a listView in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, text-size

I finished my app and would add some features. Ad example the user can change the text size. So i have Have created an activity where you can select the text size. Here is the code:

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity {
RadioButton r1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);


    RadioGroup rdgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    r1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClasseDiAppoggio.setSize(10);
        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the code of class ClasseDiAppoggi:

```
public class ClasseDiAppoggio {
private static float size = 20;

public static void setSize(float sizex){
    size = sizex;
}

public static float getSize(){
    return size;
}
}
```

And here is the code of the Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
static View globalView;
private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();
public final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;
public String textToSay;
private int mCurrentTtsPosition = -1;
Boolean testCheck = false;
public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, list);

    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (list.get(position).getVersion() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (list.get(position).getVersion() == 2) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (list.get(position).getVersion() == 3) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (list.get(position).getVersion() == 4) {
        return 4;
    }
    if (list.get(position).getVersion() == 5) {
        return 5;
    }

    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 6;
}

public void onStopTts(){
    mCurrentTtsPosition = -1;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public TextView text2;
    public CheckBox checkbox;
    public TextView textSeparator;
    public Button btncheck;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (this.getItemViewType(position)== 0){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.title_row, null);
            viewHolder.textSeparator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView, viewHolder.textSeparator);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textSeparator.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    } else if (this.getItemViewType(position)== 2){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.sub_title_row, null);
            viewHolder.textSeparator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView, viewHolder.textSeparator);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textSeparator.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }  else if (this.getItemViewType(position)== 4){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_tri_title, null);

            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView5, viewHolder.text);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    } else if (this.getItemViewType(position)== 5){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_tri, null);
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView3, viewHolder.text);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;

    } else if (this.getItemViewType(position)== 3){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.button_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.btncheck = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btncheck);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.btncheck, viewHolder.btncheck);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;

        viewHolder.btncheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (Model i: list) {

                    if (i.getVersion() == 1) {
                        if (!i.isSelected()) {
                            testCheck = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(testCheck){
                    OneFragment.startSpeak("è stato controllato tutto");
                } else {
                    OneFragment.startSpeak("Manca qualcosa, ricontrolla");

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox, viewHolder.checkbox);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setTextSize(ClasseDiAppoggio.getSize());
    viewHolder.text2.setTextSize(ClasseDiAppoggio.getSize());

    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.text2.setText(list.get(position).getName2());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
        }
    });
    final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    final View finalConvertView = convertView;
    globalView = convertView;

    if (position == mCurrentTtsPosition){
        chk.setChecked(true);
    }

    chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int getPosition = (Integer) chk.getTag();


            if (chk.isChecked()) {
                testCheck = true;

                String textPart1 = " ";
                String textPart2 = " ";
                String textToSay = " ";

                TextView label2 = (TextView) finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
                TextView label1 = (TextView) finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.label);


                textPart1 = label2.getText().toString();

                int doItearator = 1;
                if ((getPosition + 1) < list.size()) {
                    boolean testItem = false;
                    do {
                        if ((list.get(getPosition + doItearator).getVersion() == 1)) {
                            textPart2 = list.get(getPosition + doItearator).getName();
                           break;
                         } else {
                            if ((getPosition + 2) == list.size() || (getPosition + 3) == list.size()) {
                                break;
                            }
                            ++doItearator;
                        }
                   } while (testItem == false);
                }

                textToSay = textPart1 +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        "\n" + "." +
                        textPart2;

                OneFragment.startSpeak(textToSay);
            } else {
                testCheck = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

So the code works, but the problem is that the size change when i scroll the listview. So to so changes in the code should scroll down and after scroll up so that i can see the changes of text size.
How can i do that the changes are immediate?
Thanks, and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `youView.invalidate()` that should work.

You could also try `ListView.invalidateViews()` . this forces the listview to redraw its items. call it when you change the textSize.

In your case you can use `listView.invalidateViews()` in `onResume()` of the fragment_one. or to simplify you can just shift your `listView.setAdapter()` to `onResume()` then it will work

Comment: Where should i write it?

Comment: Wherever after you change your text size

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi after you change the text size. let me know if it works

Comment: @shreyas I have added it in the adapter, after i change the text with:
    viewHolder.text.setTextSize(ClasseDiAppoggio.getSize());
but it doesn't work

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi are your list and button to change the text size in the same activity.

Comment: @shreyas  No. The button for change text is in activity_options, and the listView is in fragment_one

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi ok so the user goes to activity or fragment to set the textsize and presses back to come back to the list again.In that case you can use listView.invalidateViews() in onResume() of the fragment_one. or to simplify you can just shift your  listView.setAdapter() to onResume then it will work.

Comment: @MarcoShepMonkeyDeRossi i have just edited the answer to include everything that is in the comment  to the answer for completeness.